# Access control within REST API (CXF)

Tags: rest, permissions, authorization

We plan to add fine-grained authorization to our existing RESTful API, implemented with Apache CXF. There are a handful of roles, each with a few dozens of permissions. What we need to do is to map the permissions to our endpoints/operations and decide whether the given set of permission is capable of this operation on this resource. The authentication and currently very simple access control is done with Spring Security.

Just wondering if there exists any framework/library helpful for this purpose. Any suggestions/hints/clues would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

set up a little POC with Apache Shiro and it worked exactly I want it. Shiro has this url path mapping and HttpMethodPermissionFilter so it can be configured for every URL, the privilege need to access the URL. And HttpMethodPermissionFilter is taking care of the operations. Sweet!

Make sure noSessionCreation filter is included in the chain so it goes stateless